# google cluster giving authentication scope error

Tags: kubernetes, google-app-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a free tier account but whenever i try to create a container cluster i am getting below error from one of the script

**(gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Request had insufficient authentication 
scopes.**

for other script it is giving similar error.

: googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes., forbidden

May i know how i can resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the IAM roles for the "Compute Engine default service account" and make sure it has enough permission to run the command [2]. Usually it would have an owner or editor role.

If you are on the Google Cloud Console, when creating an instance you need to look for the 'Identity and API access' section, and select 'Allow full access to all Cloud APIs' [1]

[1]https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances?hl=en_US&_ga=2.168486115.-390700867.1538154355
[2]https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 : gcloud init

Step 2 : Select [2] Create a new configuration

Step 3 : Enter configuration name. Names start with a lower case letter and contain only lower case letters a-z, digits 0-9, and hyphens '-': kubernetes-service-account

Step 4 : Choose the account you would like to use to perform operations for this configuration:[2] Log in with a new account

Step 5 : Do you want to continue (Y/n)? y

Step 6 : Copy paste the link to brwoser and login with the ID which is used to create your google Cloud Account

Step 7 : Copy the verification code provided by google after login and paste it in to the console.

Step 8 : Pick cloud project to use:

Step 9: Do you want to configure a default Compute Region and Zone? (Y/n)? y

Step 10 : Please enter numeric choice or text value (must exactly match list item): 8

Your Google Cloud SDK is configured and ready to use!